# Adjusting authoryear style of biblatex, weird space inserted by mkbibparens

Tags: biblatex

I am currently in the process of customizing the authoryear biblatex style, but I have still something I can't seem to figure out: I want the list of editors to be printed out and afterwards "eds" should be shown in parenthesis. Therefore I created a custom macro `\usebibmacro{editors+parens}`:

```
\newbibmacro*{editors+parens}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
  {}
  {\newunit\newblock%
   \printnames{editor}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \mkbibparens{\bibstring{editors}}}}
```

And I adjusted the driver for `incollection` to use that macro:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  ...
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{editors+parens}
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  ...
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

However, the result ultimately looks like this:

[image]

So, on the one hand `mkbibparens` seems to insert an extra space and secondly, there lacks a space between the editors and the first opening brace.

Can someone help me deal with this? It should in the end look like `<List of Editors><space>(eds.)<space><Title>`

All the best,
David Becher

Comment: To ensure that the suggested solutions really work with your code you should consider posting a [complete MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). It gives people something to play around with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` has a very fancy mechanism to get punctuation right. Because of this mechanism you can hardly ever use punctuation commands directly in a macro. Punctuation should only be added via `\setunit`, `\printunit` and friends, `\DeclareFieldFormat` or `\printtext`. See also §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), especially §4.11.7.2 *Common Mistakes*, p. 243-244.

In your case

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

should be enough. If you use the standard macro `editor+others` instead of your `editors+parens`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that (almost) works: `editor+others` apparently inserts an additional year, so i got `(eds.) (2000)`. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Then use `\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}` instead.

Comment: @DavidBecher See above. If that does not help, consider posting a proper MWE.

Comment: By the way: is there a difference between using `\space` as opposed to using `\addspace`?

Comment: @DavidBecher Yes there is. `\addspace`makes sure to clear any preceding space, `\space` does not. In constructs such as `\addcomma\space`/`\addcomma\addspace` they behave the same way though.

Comment: @DavidBecher If my answers helped you, please consider accepting and up-voting them. That is the preferred way to say *thank you* on this site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31299/discussion-between-david-becher-and-moewe).