# \bibstring adds period inside brackets

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to write my own `biblatex` style and my citation norms require that I add "[S.l.: s.n.]" after the title when there's no address and no publisher information. So I tried doing something like this (but with my own custom `bibstrings`, these are here just as an example):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{salaman1985,
 author  ={Redcliffe N. Salaman},
 year    =1985,
 title   ={The History and Social Influence of the Potato}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=standard, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  %\addperiod\addspace
  \brackettext{\bibstring{volume}\addcolon\addnbspace\bibstring{number}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
  \cite{salaman1985}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which prints "…of the Potato[. Vol.: no.]", with a period inside the brackets. If I uncomment that line that says `\addperiod\addspace` the period is gone, but there's still a space there before "Vol." and `\unspace` doesn't remove it.

What I want, of course, is "…of the Potato. [Vol.: no.]".

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\brackettext`, use `\printtext[brackets]` instead.

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  %\addperiod\addspace
  \printtext[brackets]{\bibstring{volume}\addcolon\addnbspace\bibstring{number}}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

This has to do with how `biblatex` handles punctuation with its punctuation tracker. You can read up on it in §4.11.7 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and especially §4.11.7.2 *Common Mistakes*. The tracker does not "see" your `\brackettext`, but it sees `\printtext[brackets]`

Comment: See also [Adjusting authoryear style of biblatex, weird space inserted by mkbibparens](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277310/35864)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I had searched for `\brackettext`, `\parentext` and `\bibstring` for a long time and couldn't find anything related, should have searched for `mkbibparens` too, I'm still getting the hang of all the commands for similar things.